# How can a sharepoint form library be set up to allow users to submit forms, but not see other people's forms

Tags: sharepoint, forms, infopath

This use case seems like it would apply to just about every form, but I have yet to find a good out-of-the-box solution for it.  Imagine an HR Complaint form based on InfoPath and SharePoint.  All Employees should be able to fill them out and submit them, and possibly see the ones they've submitted, but only members of HR should be able to view others' forms. How can I configure the form and/or the form library to accomodate this?  Some things I've tried:
[[NFL-LIVE]]#Philadelphia Eagles vs Jacksonville Jaguars: 2018 Live Stream (NFL-FOOTBALL) ON TV CHANNEL
 - Creating a Form Library View filtered where CreatedBy=[Me].  Security cannot be set on views, so users can still see all submitted forms if they choose a different view.
 - Adjusting security on the library.  It is not possible (AFAIK) to give a user 'submit' rights without also giving them 'view' rights.
 - Creating a custom workflow.  This might work, but we would prefer an out-of-the-box solution or 3rd party feature to enable this scenario, without requiring code for each form.  We want non-developer end-users to be able to create InfoPath forms with this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is bit tricky to do it in the Out Of the Box. There is no option that will let a user to View only his item and not others. Though you can get this using the Item Level Permission but you have to do it manually for each of the item that is getting created. One best option that you can do is to create a Event Handler for the List that will assign the Item Level Permission for the List Item on Item Added. I have done something similar to this in past using the Event Handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with Holiday Requests forms (and we now use it for all forms that we create). Only HR, the user's manager or the 'creator' of the form can open a full view. I'm not a Sharepoint or Infopath expert so my solution may not fit all scenarios.

background - InfoPath 2010 Form filler (not browser forms), with SharePoint wss3.0 (though I don't see why it wouldn't work on later versions).

I designed an Infopath form, with several views, opened on form load dependant on who the user is, and what the status is. One of the views is a 'sorry, you can't open this form' view.

When the form is created I move the userid (a built-in function on the form - userName()) to a field 'created by'. When the form is opened a rule checks that field against the current user field and can take action to show the appropriate view (depending on other field values). I also move their manager's userid to another field - this is also retrieved from a data connection to another list

Then I have a SharePoint List (called permissions) - this list contains userids and what their permission is (senior manager, HR etc) and I read this using a data connection, and filter it on the userid (retrieved when the form is opened).

So, in summary - when the form opens,the Form Load rule:
1) retrieves current userid
2) retrieves that user's permissions from my list
3) checks the Form status

and then shows the appropriate view of the form (update, read-only, private etc)

I created a new permission type which is a copy of 'contribute' settings, but without the delete permission. So by default everyone can in theory add, read and update all forms, but my rules prevent certain actions.

Someone with more knowledge of SharePoint & InfoPath than me might be able to find fault with it, and it might not be 100% secure in the true sense, but it works for us. I also remove the 'Open in Windows Explorer' options from the tool bar so they can't see the raw xml data.

I hope this helps

Comment: You've obscured the most common ways for somebody to see something that is not "theirs", but it is not "secure" at the SharePoint level. It would be possible to get access to data the user doesn't own (for example, they could run Fiddler and see the XML when they open a form they shouldn't).  Still, this might be sufficient for some forms depending on how sensitive the data is...

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by editing the settings on the list/library in question and then adding the HR users to an administrator group.

The settings can be found by going to the **List/Library** tab and clicking on **List/Library Settings**. Then click on **Advanced Settings** and the section you are looking for is the second section is called **Item-level Premissions**.

To set the list so people can only see those I temst created by the user select the radio button next to **Read items that were created by the user**.

To set the list so that only people who created the item can edit it select the radio button next to **Create items and edit items that were created by the user**.

Then create a permissions group that has full control and add the HR users to it. Thus they should be able to see all the items.

Comment: That option is not available for form libraries, just for lists.  It does accommodate _some_ scenarios, though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly when I say that I believe an Out Of The Box solution exists by enabling content approval from the library settings.   As long as the content is never toggled to accepted, it can be set so that the only people who see the form are the submitter and the persons with approve access to this list.   So if you have approve access you can see everyone's results.    If you toggle it to accept the content, everyone would then see the form.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use InfoPath to create a custom list, instead of a form library. Unfortunately, this may require you to rebuild the whole thing (but maybe look into the "Convert Existing Form" option). To build a custom list using InfoPath, simply open InfoPath Designer and select "SharePoint List" as the template you want to build. Then start designing the form. There are certainly downsides to this, like the fact that you can't simply redirect a form to a new location, but you could build the list in one location, export it as a template, then import it at a new location. Another concern is that you can't save the form locally before submitting it. But pretty much all other functionality exists with the custom list designer. I've even found a few small things that lists built this way can do better than InfoPath forms, mobile compatibility is one.

Answer (score 0):

JP's answer above worked for me.

Let's say you want two user groups 'Form Users' and 'Form Owners'. Form Owners gets full control for entire site and Form users get Contribute access only for the list.

First go to Advanced settings under the 'Site Settings -> Site Libraries & Lists -> Your List'.

Select your preference in the Item Level Permissions section which grants read/create/edit access to creator of the item. Click OK.

Then click on 'Permissions for this List' and click 'Stop Inheriting Permissions' for that list and then add 'Form Users' to the permitted groups with contribute level access. You can add Everyone to the 'Form Users' group and share the link to the form on your intranet for all employees to access. Whereas Form owners can see all items.